# How do you pass parameters using Backbone.history.navigate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am just getting started with Backbone.js and was wondering how can I send parameters using `Backbone.history.navigate`?  Currently I have the following in place:

```
Backbone.history.navigate("classrooms", true)
```

This sends the page to:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile#classrooms
```

What I would want the URL to look like is:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile#classrooms?size=300
```

What syntax would I use to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hand that fragment straight to `navigate`:

```
Backbone.history.navigate("classrooms?size=300", true)
```

Everything should work fine if your routes are set up properly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f27yv/

Comment: How do I access the variable in say an alert after the redirect?

Comment: @Goalie: Depends on your routes, it should get passed to your callback if things are set up properly, see the jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: The example is using the windows.location.hash to get the value of size.  I want to be able to get that value in the controller.  Is that possible?  You can't use windows.location.hash for that.

Comment: @Goalie: In the Rails controller? You can't, the remote server will never see the fragment part of the URL.